# Prioritize Spotify when pressing media keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, shortcuts, spotify

I have media keys on my laptop's numpad (play/pause, stop, previous, next) and so far, even if the Spotify app was not focused, those keys would trigger an action in it. But for some reason, now they'll trigger actions in whatever tabs I have opened in Chrome (e.g., youtube). Is there any way I can make the keyboard prioritize Spotify whenever it is open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the exact same problem, found the solution on Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/spotify/comments/bf3pmv/pause_button_not_prioritizing_spotify/

"Chrome added media key support.

Go to "chrome://flags/ " and search for Hardware Media Key Handling.

Disable that and you should be good =)"

Fixed it for me instantly!

Comment: For those who care: I believe this will make it so media keys can't be used in Chrome.