# Chrome is eating my media key inputs and Spotify does not register them. Cannot use keyboard play/pause button while Chrome is open

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard, spotify, media-keys

I'm using a PC with Windows 10.

Normally, my media keys on my keyboard (e.g. play, pause, skip) control Spotify just fine.  But while I have Chrome open, these media keys do nothing to control spotify.  When I press them, nothing happens.  I've researched this issue and I've seen many answers similar to [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Chrome-is-eating-my-Media-Key-inputs-cannot-control-Spotify/m-p/4960922) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1429054/prioritize-spotify-when-pressing-media-keys)

**I have already set Hardware Media Key Handling to disabled**, and restarted both Chrome and my entire PC.

[image: IMG:]

The problem STILL REMAINS.  While Chrome is open, I cannot use my media keys to control spotify.  What is the solution here?  This only happens with Chrome. If I close Chrome, I can control spotify with my media keys again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the extension google play music disable or remove it that is what hijacks it. If you have any other extensions that are media based they may do the same thing.

Comment: If you have the extension google play music, disable or remove it, that is what hijacks it. If you have any other extensions that are media based they may do the same thing.